# How to undo `nix-channel --update`

Tags: nix, nixos

After clean installation via NixOps, I logined to machine and executed

```
# nix-channel --update
```

This pulled ~130Mb of nixpkgs into my `/nix/store`. How can I undo this?

Comment: Best to recreate the machine, you can't revert the first channel.

Comment: If this actually updated the channel, `nix-channel --rollback` will undo that (but not free up disk space). If this failed due to lack of disk space, good news is nothing changed to the system setup, and `nix-collect-garbage` should free that back up.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On a normal Nix or NixOS install, if you've updated your channels by accident with `nix-channel --update`, you can undo this by running

```
nix-channel --rollback
```

See [the manual](http://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-nix-channel) for more details.

On a NixOps installation, channels are configured but not actually used. See the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39108713/582) for that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get `error: no generation older than the current (1) exists`

Answer (score 5):

On a NixOps installation it seems that channels are configured, but aren't actually used by NixOps. This means that running `nix-channel --update` will create the very first generation, and `nix-channel --rollback` won't work as that can't roll back past the first generation.

The following seems to work for clearing out this information.

**Do not run this on a Nix or NixOS install!** This is just for NixOps.

```
rm /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels-1-link
rm /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels
rm ~/.nix-defexpr/channels
nix-collect-garbage -d
```

Comment: Don't do this! You just deleted your channels.

Comment: lold. This is actually what OP (me) asked. NixOps deployed machines don't have channels by default.

Comment: If there are no channels then what did `nix-channel --update` pull from? This suggests that there were in fact channels configured.

Comment: I've just checked a fresh libvirtd NixOps deployment. nix-channel --list shows `nixos https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-unstable`, so yes, there is a channel, which is not pulled. After it is pulled first time, `nix-channel --rollback` doesn't unpull it back. You have either to use suggested solution or 1) delete channel 2) GC 3) readd channel

Comment: @danbst this is maybe how _you_ interpret your question but a lot of other readers interpret it otherwise and this for them is harmful advice.

Comment: okay, I've changed an accepted answer to popular one. I hope if anyone will have my problem, they'll still find my current answer to this particular problem.

Comment: I'm going to update both answers to make it more clear what question each answer is actually answering.